# Can't move an object using setInterval function

Tags: javascript

I want to make a rectangular move by click on a button and stop it clicking on the same button. Here is a part of my code:

```
document.getElementById("startStop").addEventListener("click", changePlace);

function changePlace() {
nIntervMove = setInterval(movement, 100);
};


var tmp1 = 0; 
function movement() {
  var oElem = document.getElementById("colorRectangular");
  oElem.getPropertyValue = tmp1;
  tmp1 += "10px";
 };

 function stopMove(){
     clearInterval(nIntervMove);
 };
```

Comment: `console.log(tmp1)` and at least one of your problems should be obvious.

Comment: `getPropertyValue()` is a *function* of an element's `.style` object.  You are using it incorrectly.  What *exactly* are you trying to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty straight forward:

```
var makeMove = function(x, hx, t, complete) {

    var target = document.getElementById('rect'),
        dx = 0,
        d = setInterval(function() {
            target.style.left = dx + "px";
            dx += hx;
            if(dx >= x) {
                clearInterval(d);
                complete();
            }

        }, t);
};

makeMove(100, 5, 500, function() {
    alert('done'); 
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8ay9cqmd/